# SSH into Raspberry Pi OS Lite not working

Tags: ssh

I followed the instructions on how to enable SSH and get my Rasberry Pi connected to my network.  I do see the device on the network and when SSH into it I do get the screen to validate the authentication key as I would expect.  When I try to login as user pi with raspberry as the password I just get an error stating that the username or password is incorrect.  I've also tried with a blank password with no luck.

Is there a different login for Raspberry Pi OS lite?

I can go through the install with a regular version but I'm trying to keep this headless to stay as lightweight as possible.

Comment: What OS? There's a new scheme with RaspiOS 22-04-04 that doesn't add the default user=pi password=raspberry to a new install.

Answer (score 5):

If this is a new install the Pi will have whatever user/password you created it with.

https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/

Did you read the detail in the link - this explains "For people who run their Raspberry Pi headless and therefore cannot work through the wizard, the Raspberry Pi Imager tool allows you to preconfigure an image with a user account"

Comment: This works with the full version but not with the Lite OS.  You don't get a wizard to create the SSH user.  However I wasn't using Raspberry Pi Imager.  I was using ballenaEtcher based on a tutorial I was following.  Looks like with Raspberry Pi Imager you can go into advanced options.

Comment: If you choose NOT to use the recommended tool you need a screen/keyboard. ANY earlier tutorial won't apply to the latest image - which works like most Linux installs. Having said that it also explains how to setup without the imager (using userconf), although this is clumsy.

Comment: just tried full version and it doesn't work. Have to use the Imager tool.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the Raspberry Pi Imager and select the Lite OS (I was using ballenaEtcher).  Once I choose my storage I was able to go into the advanced options by pressing Ctrl + Shift + X to bring up the Advanced options menu before I started the write.  In the advanced option I was able to create the SSH user and password as well as set my WiFi credentials.